# CreateProcess + Call command line tool

Tags: c++, windows

I'm pretty new to threading and processes and I find I am unable to get CreateProcess() to start an executable even though there are lots of other forum posts about it. From my meagre understanding of how it works I think that I have the right parameters set but I get a `Create Process failed (267)` error. The executable I am trying to run is a command line tool that belongs to the Xilinx suite called xst. What I want is to run xst in the directory that is defined by the `path` global variable so it can work on some files that are stored in there. Do I have the parameters to CreateProcess() wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <AccCtrl.h>
#include <Aclapi.h>

std::string path = "C:\\FPGA\\BSP\\BSP\\Xilinx\\SingleItemTest\\";

void testXST(std::string filePath, std::string arguements) {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcess(
        LPTSTR(filePath.c_str()),   
        LPTSTR(arguements.c_str()),         
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        LPTSTR(path.c_str()),            
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}

int main()
{
    std::string xstPath = "C:\\Xilinx\\14.7\\ISE_DS\\ISE\\bin\\nt\\xst.exe";
    std::string args = " -h";
    testXST(xstPath, args);
    return 0;
}
```

I have the environment variables set for xst so I can call it anywhere from the command line but since I am giving the direct path to the executable that shouldn't matter, correct?

Comment: `LPTSTR(filePath.c_str()),` --    Why are you casting `(LPTSTR)`??  This will not work if you are building a UNICODE application.  Remove the casts and if there are compiler errors, fix the error by using the appropriate string type(s), and not cover up the error by casting.

Comment: You need `std::wstring`. And to prefix your string literals with `L`. Then remove all of the casts.

Comment: Also, [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) carefully for `CreateProcess` if you're using the Unicode version.  The second parameter must be a writeable TCHAR buffer and not a string literal.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems here.

First, as @PaulMcKenzie pointed out in the comments, the type of the `lpCommandLine` parameter is `LPTSTR`, not `LPCTSTR`. Therefore you can't pass the return value of `std::string::c_str()`, since that returns const buffer. You will need to copy the contents of the `std::string` into a `char` array, and pass that to `CreateProcess()`.

Secondly, you aren't passing the correct value for the `lpCommandLine` parameter. The value of this isn't the arguments to the process, but rather the entire command line to execute. This must include the path to the executable in addition to any arguments. Think of this as what you would type at a command prompt to run the same thing.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I want the exe to run in a particular directory so it can access some files. Was I correct to put it into the lpCurrentDirectory parameter?

Comment: @nhoughto Yes, that's correct. The value of `lpCurrentDirectory` will be the initial working folder for the new process.